# Grabbing the contents of an excel text box into a string that keeps Line Feed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new user to the site, and new to VBA.

I'm just trying to get the contents of multiple text boxes (from many different sheets) into one sheet.

Right now, I've been stuck on getting the information from a single text box into a variable.

At this point in time, I just want it to retain the line feeds (new line, enter, return, etc).

Even if I could just copy/paste the information, at this point, I can't even access the text box via VBA.

If anyone could help out, that'd be really great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this for a start?

The following code will extract the text within the textbox and print it to the immediate view.

```
Sub ExtractTextFromShapes()

Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then Debug.Print shp.TextFrame.Characters.Caption

Next


End Sub
```

You can easily replace

`Debug.Print shp.TextFrame.Characters.Caption`

With

`strText = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Caption`